# Test-doubling a file path in Java/Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy

I am trying to write a unit test for a helper method in my `ApiRequestHandler` which handles `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` . This class uses an [EFS file path](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), which is where it writes files to. I have this stored in my codebase in `public final class Constants` as `public static final String EfsMountPath`.

Obviously, I cannot write to folder `Constants.EfsMountPath` on my Windows machine...

Problem is, I cannot test-double out its value, without causing issues. Attempt to use `MockFree([Constants])` breaks my test case space.

The method I am trying to test, is defined to be:

```
RequestBodyModel parseRequestEvent(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request) {
    byte[] bodyBytes = request.getBody().getBytes("UTF-8");
    if (request.getIsBase64Encoded())
        bodyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bodyBytes);

    RequestBodyModel model = new RequestBodyModel();

    FileUpload.parse(bodyBytes, request.getHeaders().get('Content-Type'))
        .each { FileItem fileItem ->
            if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("inputFile")) {
                File inputFile = FileUtils.CreateFileIfNotExists("${Constants.EfsMountPath}/${FileUtils.InputPathPart}/${fileItem.getName()}");
                fileItem.write(inputFile);
                model.inputFile = inputFile;
                return;
            }

            if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("outputFileExtension")) {
                model.outputFileExtension = fileItem.getString();
                return;
            }

            if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("shouldExportDncRecords")) {
                model.shouldExportDncRecords = Boolean.valueOf(fileItem.getString());
                return;
            }
        }

    return model;
}
```

What is the best way to make this testable w.r.t. the input file path ?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to exploit that Groovy allows [parameters with default values](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-parameters-with-default.html).

```
RequestBodyModel parseRequestEvent(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request, Constants constants = new Constants()) {    
    byte[] bodyBytes = request.getBody().getBytes("UTF-8");
    if (request.getIsBase64Encoded())
        bodyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bodyBytes);

    RequestBodyModel model = new RequestBodyModel();

    FileUpload.parse(bodyBytes, request.getHeaders().get('Content-Type'))
        .each { FileItem fileItem ->
            if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("inputFile")) {
                File inputFile = FileUtils.CreateFileIfNotExists("${constants.EfsMountPath}/${FileUtils.InputPathPart}/${fileItem.getName()}");
                fileItem.write(inputFile);
                model.inputFile = inputFile;
                return;
            }

            if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("outputFileExtension")) {
                model.outputFileExtension = fileItem.getString();
                return;
            }

            if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("shouldExportDncRecords")) {
                model.shouldExportDncRecords = Boolean.valueOf(fileItem.getString());
                return;
            }
        }

    return model;
}
```

Done this way `constants` is an overridable default value that your test suite is free to change to whatever it wants.

Passing it in at the method level may seem a little klunky. And it is. This could also have been passed to the constructor that built the object that houses this method.

You should provide a way to configure your code base differently for multiple builds. Not focus only on one and make others hack their way in.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

- create a `PathProvider` that has two methods:

  - `getBaseInputPath`
  - `getBaseOutputPath`

It is defined to be:

```
class PathProvider {
    String getBaseInputPath() {
        return "${Constants.EfsMountPath}/${FileUtils.InputPathPart}";
    }

    String getBaseOutputPath() {
        return "${Constants.EfsMountPath}/${FileUtils.OutputPathPart}";
    }
}
```

- put a child `PathProvider` in my `ApiRequestHandler` class
- in the test case, we create instance of `ApiRequestHandler` with a `TestPathProvider`, defined to be:

```
class TestPathProvider extends PathProvider {
    @Override
    String getBaseInputPath() {
        return "${FileUtils.TestDirectoryPath}/input";
    }

    @Override
    String getBaseOutputPath() {
        return "${FileUtils.TestDirectoryPath}/output";
    }
}
```

The `parseRequestEvent` then becomes:

```
    RequestBodyModel parseRequestEvent(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request) {
        byte[] bodyBytes = request.getBody().getBytes("UTF-8");
        if (request.getIsBase64Encoded())
            bodyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bodyBytes);

        RequestBodyModel model = new RequestBodyModel();

        FileUpload.parse(bodyBytes, request.getHeaders().get('Content-Type'))
            .each { FileItem fileItem ->
                if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("inputFile")) {
                    File inputFile = FileUtils.CreateFileIfNotExists("${this.pathProvider.getBaseInputPath()}/${fileItem.getName()}");
                    fileItem.write(inputFile);
                    model.inputFile = inputFile;
                    return;
                }

                if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("outputFileExtension")) {
                    model.outputFileExtension = fileItem.getString();
                    return;
                }

                if (fileItem.getFieldName().equals("shouldExportDncRecords")) {
                    model.shouldExportDncRecords = Boolean.valueOf(fileItem.getString());
                    return;
                }
            }

        return model;
    }
```

This takes care of other test cases too, such as testing the actual `handleRequest` method, that is to create an output file and return it in an `ApiGatewayProxyResponseEvent`...but I have yet to write those